# Can I delete my own post with answers?

Tags: support

I want to delete my own post as a question, but when I try, it says " you can't answer a question that has answers" . Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete your own question, but **not** if it has been answered. Others have taken time and effort to provide an answer, and it would not be fair to deny them reputation for that contribution.

See [Deleting my own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96670/deleting-my-own-question) on MSO, the SE-wide meta, which provides more details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can delete your own question, but not if it has been answered and the answer has been upvoted. Others have taken time and effort to read and provide an upvote, and it would not be fair to deny their contribution and their time.

Comment: Did you just copy/paste/edit another person's answer? Your edits don't really add anything.

Comment: @Mitch, no, I added 'the answer has been upvoted' which is not reported in the other answer. In fact you can delete a question until its answer, if posted, has no upvotes. After the first upvote you cannot delete the question anymore. Clear?