# I cant delete my question

Tags: discussion

Sorry I have been unable to delete due to lack of knowledge.

Comment: The delete button should be right under your post (except in the extremely unlikely case of being on the app, in which case you need to open the post in a browser).

Comment: ironically, an author cannot delete their question if it has been answered and that **answer has been upvoted**. See [Can I delete my own post with answers?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4295/can-i-delete-my-own-post-with-answers)

Answer (score 3):

It's always a good idea to include a [link to the post you're asking about](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/520535/revisions).

Normally there's a list of possible actions under the tags, opposite your user card. Here's the moderator list, and not everyone will have all these options; but **delete** is included where it can be.

[image: Delete action on question]

While the Delete button/link should be under your post using the website [using the app it probably won't be], there are restrictions.

In particular, people with less than 20k rep need to wait two days to remove a question. If a question is worth asking, it's worth answering. Since you asked the question, it must be worth asking. If you have a change of heart, you need to wait and see if anyone will in fact answer it. If there aren't answers which disqualify it from deletion, you can delete it once the time limit has expired.

After the time limit, with less than 10k rep you can only delete your own question if there is at *most* one answer and that answer has no upvotes. That restriction is there because people have worked on answers which the community have thought to be worthwhile. Just because you're no longer interested in getting answers to your question should not allow others to lose the rep they have gained through their own work.

Members of the community who have the post-delete privilege (at least 10k rep) can still vote to delete the question if it warrants it. It takes at least three votes, possibly more.

Note that vandalising a question is **very bad practice** and will normally result in the question being reverted. That's far too complicated to do here (where the edited question has been migrated, and the migrated question is useful), but *this* question should not be regarded as a precedent.

Comment: Actually the OP was probably talking about this very question. Just look at the revision history on the main site :p

Comment: @Laurel Aha. Thanks: answer amended accordingly. (Restrictions aren't easy to find; feel free to put anything right I've misremembered. This question is useful.)

Comment: The delete button does exist on the mobile site but I thinkt deleting posts using the SE Apple app is more problematic. If I'm not mistaken there is no delete button.  Not 100% sure though.

Comment: [Delete questions/answers in iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220639/delete-questions-answers-in-ios-app)

Comment: @Mari-LouA You can't delete via the app: the only options are Edit/Share. It appears the API restriction has not been reworked. Answer updated again.

Comment: The same is true for the android app, is that what you meant by API? Anyhow:  [Allow us to vote to delete from the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962) If the OP is using an app, it's not their fault they cannot delete an off-topic question, which it appears it was, by looking at its history.

Comment: Android is the same (I use that, not iOS) but it's not the primary interface for SE: it relies on an Application Programming Interface to make changes to the database. The primary means of doing that is the website. Mobile view should work, but most smartphones will also cope with desktop view, if that's different. [Looks like the app can't edit comments either!]

Comment: +1 for “In particular, people with less than 20k rep need to wait two days to remove a question.” this probably explains why there are so many users on SO banned from posting questions. Even if they realise their post is off-topic and they want to delete it, they cannot. That post attracts downvotes and maybe an easy upvoted answer, and that user is stuck with a downvoted question but with an upvoted answer.